# How to get WordPress term attached to the Post?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, terms

How to retrieve all WordPress terms attached to the Post and Other Post type?
Assumed I don't know/don't care about the taxonomy, term name/term id etc, the only thing I know is post_id.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

There's a function specifically for this, it's called [`wp_get_post_terms()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_post_terms).

Unfortunately, you *do* need to care about the taxonomy.  If you don't specify a taxonomy, it will return all of the "post_tags" terms:

```
$terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post_id, $taxonomy, $args )
```

- `$post_id` is the ID of the post you're working with (defaults to 0)
- `$taxonomy` is the name of the taxonomy for which you want to retrieve terms (defaults to "post_tags"
- `$args` is an array of overrides of other default parameters (see the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_post_terms) for details)

Comment: hello, thanks. but if I only passes $post_id, will return empty array if current post type don't have any tags taxonomy attached

Comment: Exactly, that's why I said you *do* need to care about the taxonomy.  If you don't pass in a taxonomy, it gets the terms associated with the "post_tags" taxonomy.

Answer (score 2):

Hmm.  You could try getting all taxonomies and getting all terms associated with the post ID and taxonomy.

```
$taxonomies = get_taxonomies( '', 'names' );
$terms = wp_get_object_terms($post->ID, $taxonomies);
```

I haven't had a chance to try this out myself.

Comment: almost there, but in this case, I don't know 'names'  



finally i got this:  

`$custom_post_type = get_post_type_object(get_post_type(get_the_id()));  
   
   echo '<pre>';  
   $args = Array('object_type'=>array($custom_post_type->name));  
   $all_tax = get_taxonomies($args);  
   foreach($all_tax as $tax){  
    $all_terms = wp_get_object_terms(get_the_id(), $tax);  
    print_r($all_terms);  
   }  
   echo '</pre>'; `  

Thanks, solved :)

Comment: 'names' isn't a taxonomy.  It is the return type.  So get_taxonomies( '', 'names' ) would return an array of taxonomy names.

Comment: oh ok.  
but if I don't pass first argument with object type, it will return all taxonomies, not only which is attached to the current post.  here is the difference:  
`echo '<pre>';  
 print_r(get_taxonomies('','names'));  
echo '</pre>';`


Versus

`$tax_args   = Array('object_type'=>array($post_type_name));  
  
echo '<pre>';  
 print_r(get_taxonomies($tax_args,'names'));  
echo '</pre>';`

thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

To get all terms for all taxonomies attached to a post, you can use this function:

```
function my_post_terms() {

    // Get an array of all taxonomies for this post
    $taxonomies = get_taxonomies( '', 'names' );

    // Are there any taxonomies to get terms from?
    if ( $taxonomies ) {    

        // Call the wp_get_post_terms function to retrieve all terms. It accepts an array of taxonomies as argument. 
        $arr_terms = wp_get_post_terms( get_the_ID(), array_values( $taxonomies ) , array( "fields" => "names" ) );

        // Convert the terms array to a string
        $terms = implode( ' ',$arr_terms );

        // Get out of here
        return $terms;
    }
}
```

Now you can use it in your templates:

```
<?php echo my_post_terms(); ?>
```

If you need an HTML list of all terms or links, simply loop over the $arr_terms array.